# android inapp-billing - find out API version

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm pretty sure that i'm using Inapp-billing v3 in my app ("IInAppBillingService.aidl" is v3 as far as i know - "IMarketBillingService.aidl" would be v2 according to the google-documentation).

however, i received an email from google asking me to update my app from v2 to v3 as at least one purchase was made using the old API in the past 3 months.

Also - i never had V2 implemented in my app so an old version should not be the case.

Is this a mistake by google, or was one of my uses purchasing something using a old play-store, so some kind of support/compatibility-mode was activated?

Or am i mistaking and i'm really using v2 of the api?? 
how can i find out (for sure)which version i have implemented?

this may be a stupid question, however, the email from google confused me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the same email as well and am confused by it.

I also use IInAppBillingService.aidl and within IABHelper there's a method launchPurchaseFlow which calls getBuyIntent with the first parameter being version, which is set to 3 so I'm pretty certain I'm using v3.

The IABHelper I'm using is littered with v3 checks and comments.

Suggest you check the same piece of code to make sure and put it down to a Google error otherwise.

Comment: i have this parameter set to 3 as well - so probably it's really a google error. however - it helps a lot to know that i'm not alone with this - thanks a lot

Comment: FWIW, I got the same message and, like you, I have been using version 3 from the beginning without any problems.

Comment: I received the same e-mail from Google and I've been using V3 from the start. If anyone finds out anything else then please post back here!