# Google In-app billing: Using In-App-Billing Version 3, still google mentioned transaction occurred in In-App-Billing Version 2

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I have a received a mail from Google mentioning 'we will end support for the In-app Billing Version 2 API. After this date, users will no longer be able to make in-app purchases using your app until you upgrade your app to use the Version 3 API.' And they have detected that my app have had a transaction on the v2 API recently.

I have implemented and using In App Billing Version 3 API for 'in app subscription' for my Android app like an year ago, from the very first day. And app transactions are going on successfully. I have checked http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html again and everything looks right. I have added IInAppBillingService.aidl and in IABHelper it shows me that In-app-billing v3 is implemented.

Could anyone please suggest how to know whether my app has been using In App Billing V2? And if necessary, how do I remove In App Billing V2 components? Do I need to update anything for In App Billing Version 3 again? Appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android inapp-billing - find out API version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821349/android-inapp-billing-find-out-api-version)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the post, I have just checked the post and I couldn't find any solution other than People are assuming it could be a Google Error. I am trying to see if I get anything more concrete.

Comment: FWIW, I got the same message and, like you, I have been using version 3 from the beginning without any problems.

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about this, I got the same email from Google, and submitted a query form, here is Google's response:

*Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support. 
I'm sorry for any confusion related to the announcement you received about support ending for the In-App Billing Version 2 API. If you've already migrated to Version 3, there’s no action necessary. 
I reviewed the apps you mentioned in our system and verified that the apps haven’t generated any revenue in the past 90 days using In-App Billing Version 2. Also, if you spent time reviewing your implementation of the In-App Billing API and discovered that you’ve already migrated to Version 3, I sincerely apologize for any inconvenience that this caused. 
Again, I apologize for any confusion and time spent reviewing your In-App Billing implementation. Please let us know if you have any additional questions and I'll be happy to help.*

Answer (score 1):

I got the same mail from Google, and likewise never have used API v.2 for billing. Wondering if maybe its related to auth - we do use public API method to validate purchases after the fact... trying to query Google and will reply if I get more info.

Comment: I got the same message as well and it's taken me by surprise since I've been using V3 since day one. Please post back with anything you find out.

Answer (score 0):

I also receive this reply from them:

> I'm sorry for any confusion related to the announcement you received
>   about support ending for the In-App Billing Version 2 API. If you've
>   already migrated to Version 3, there’s no action necessary.
>
> ......if you spent time reviewing your
>   implementation of the In-App Billing API and discovered that you’ve
>   already migrated to Version 3, I sincerely apologize for any
>   inconvenience that this caused.